# run code automatically after view appeared

Tags: swift, swiftui, onappear

Is there a way of running code after the view appeared? If I use ".onAppear", my code gets executed and when it is finished, the view appears. But I want that the view appears first and then my code gets executed automatically. Thanks

Comment: Did you try a .task _{} in place or after .onAppear {} ?

Comment: Never know you could use task like that but I will try and tell the results

Comment: You can add Dispatchque with some seconds delay.

Comment: SwiftUI does not report "appear visible on screen" state, so either use UIKit (say via representable) or, better, do not refer on that at all. BTW, SwiftUI.onAppear means "appear in view hierarchy" (equivalent to `didMoveToSuperview`).